# Instagram Api for send direct message from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, instagram

Is there any C# solution for send or get Instagram direct message.
I had been researched instagram api but i can not send direct message from c#

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately/fortunately no.

The public Api's got a big restriction in 2016, and now there is not any instagrams public api for private messages.

Comment: I saw some examples in php but couldn't find it in c#

Comment: I believe it was an example made before 2016, also it actually doesn't matter what language, as long as you have an endpoint where to get the information, check the php example that you saw, take the endpoint and check the status of it, it won't be available anymore.